# How can I pass values or fields from one page to another page in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I send the value of the checkbox to the checkout.js page? This is the PaymentForm page. I tried my best but it's not working correctly. Basically, I want to use the PaymentForm fields in checkout.js page because my submit button is there.

**PaymentForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import { createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';


const styles = createStyles({
    formControlLabel: {
        fontSize: '1.5rem',
        '& label': { fontSize: '5rem' }
    }
});

const handleToken = (token) => {

    console.log(token);
}

const PaymentForm = ({ PaymentForm, changePaymentForm }) => {


    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        checkedA: false,
    });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });

    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                Payment method
            </Typography><br />
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                     <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox checked={state.checkedA} onChange={handleChange} name="checkedA"/>}
                        label={<Typography style={styles.formControlLabel}>Cash on delivery</Typography>}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <StripeCheckout
                        stripeKey="pk_test_51I9XPQAesAg2GfzQyVB7VgP0IbmWwgcfeFJSuCpB2kbNu60AFTbFhC7dxwje8YF4w2ILMJ6o2InB9ENczpd4dCSa00e09XoDbw"
                        token={handleToken}
                        amount={2 * 100}
                        name="All Products"

                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

**Checkout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import axios from '../../axios-orders';
import AddressForm from './CheckoutForm';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm';
import Review from './Review';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    position: 'relative',
  },

  layout: {
    width: 'auto',
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up(1000 + theme.spacing(2) * 2)]: {
      width: 1100,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',

    },

  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up(700 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 246, 244)',

    },

  },
  stepper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(5, 0, 5),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 246, 244)',


  },
  buttons: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',

  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    border: "none"    
  },
}));

const steps = ['Shipping address', 'Payment details', 'Review your order'];

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                  Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

function getStepContent(step, formValues = null, changeFormValue = null, paymentValues = null, changePaymentValue = null) {
  switch (step) {
  case 0:
    return <AddressForm addressValues={formValues} changeAddressValue={changeFormValue} />;
  case 1:
    return <PaymentForm PaymentForm={paymentValues} changePaymentForm={changePaymentValue}/>;
  case 2:
    return <Review />;
  default:
    throw new Error('Unknown step');
  }
}

export default function Checkout(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [addressFormValues, setAddressFormValues] = React.useState({});
  const [paymentFormValues, setPaymentFormValues] = React.useState({});
  const [paymentFormNewValues, setPaymentFormNewValues] = React.useState({});
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);

  if(paymentFormValues === true){
    setPaymentFormNewValues('Cash')
  }
  if(paymentFormValues === false){
    setPaymentFormNewValues('Online')
  }
  console.log('[paymentFormNewValues: ]', paymentFormNewValues)
  console.log('[paymentFormValues: ]', paymentFormValues)

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);

    axios.post('/UserPortal/CartItems/checkout_details_check.php', {
        customer_id: localStorage.getItem('Id'),
    })
    .then((response) => {
    if(response.data === null)
    {
    axios.post('/UserPortal/CartItems/checkout_details.php', {
        customer_id: localStorage.getItem('Id'),
        firstname: addressFormValues.firstname,
        lastname: addressFormValues.lastname,
        address: addressFormValues.address,
        city: addressFormValues.city,
        state: addressFormValues.state
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })  
    
}
else{  
    axios.post('/UserPortal/CartItems/checkout_details_update.php', {
            customer_id: localStorage.getItem('Id'),
            firstname: addressFormValues.firstname,
            lastname: addressFormValues.lastname,
            address: addressFormValues.address,
            city: addressFormValues.city,
            state: addressFormValues.state,
            payment_method: paymentFormNewValues
        })
        .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
       
        })     
    }

})
     

  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  };

  const changeAddressFormValue = (key, value) => {
    let values = { ...addressFormValues };
    values[key] = value;
    setAddressFormValues(values);
  };
   const changePaymentFormValue = (key, value) => {
    let values = { ...addressFormValues };
    values[key] = value;
    setPaymentFormValues(values);
  }; 

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="absolute" color="default" className={classes.appBar}></AppBar>
      <main className={classes.layout}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h3" align="center">
                        Checkout
          </Typography>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
            {steps.map((label) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel><Typography component="h1" variant="h5" align="center">
                  {label} </Typography></StepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>

          <React.Fragment>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                    Thank you for your order.
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                                    Your order number is #2001539. We have emailed your order 
                                     confirmation, and will
                                     send you an update when your order has shipped.
                </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                {activeStep === 0 ? getStepContent(activeStep, addressFormValues, changeAddressFormValue , paymentFormValues, changePaymentFormValue) : getStepContent(activeStep)}
             
                {    <div className={classes.buttons}>
                 { activeStep !== 0 && (
                    <Button variant="contained" style={{outline: 'none'}} 
                      className={classes.button}
                      onClick={handleBack}
                    >
                        Back
                    </Button>
                  )}
                  
                  <Button style={{outline: 'none'}}
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                   
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Place order' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div> }
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        </Paper>
        <Copyright />
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have checked the activeStep wrong.

Maybe the right code must be like the following:

```
<React.Fragment>
   {activeStep !== 0 ?getStepContent(activeStep, addressFormValues, changeAddressFormValue , paymentFormValues, changePaymentFormValue) : getStepContent(activeStep)}
```

Comment: If I do this then activeStep === 0 does'nt work.

Comment: Then you can remove checking activeStep part. Like this: 
`<React.Fragment>{getStepContent(activeStep, addressFormValues, changeAddressFormValue , paymentFormValues, changePaymentFormValue)}`

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever consider using Context API?

[React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

But also you can use create a checkboxValue with useState in Checkout.js and pass setCheckBoxValue to PaymentForm in getStepContent as prop. When checkbox checked trigger setCheckBoxValue and it will trigger parent component's state (Checkbox).

Comment: If you could make changes in the code it will be a great help. Please